# Datatables doesn't change selected count after removing rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using row selection in datatables (as of now, version 1.12.4). After a user performs an action (clicks a button), it needs to remove the selected rows from the datatable, so as per the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()) I've called remove on the selected rows like so:

```js
table.rows({ selected: true }).remove().draw();
```

However, after calling the above, the UI is still showing that rows are selected at the bottom of the table (even though they have been removed): e.g.

'2 rows selected'

Answer (score -1):

To work around this, before I remove the rows, I call 'deselect' on those rows to update the count. This has to come before removing the rows or the count doesn't update.

```js
var rows = table.rows({ selected: true });
rows.deselect(); 
rows.remove().draw();
```